# Finding compass direction between two distant GPS points?

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, direction, compass

I have a Latitude & Longitude for two locations (me in the West, him across the country), and a web-calculated GPS point for each. I'm trying to figure out which direction -- per my compass -- to look out "toward him" from my rooftop.

Google Maps helped me find the two strings of latitude/longitude (I'm 34.abcdef / -118.stwxyz) and a GPS of that point (I'm at 65 47 31, or however you write it), but I hope you can tell me how/where to point my compass so I aim directly at, say, 40.abcdef/-77.stwxyz.

The compass.google tool was beyond me to even get started.

Comment: Never mind! I finally found a site called SunEarthTools (seems to be for solar set ups) that helped show me how to set my compass so I can face his direction when we're on the phone -- thanks anyway!

~ @TheGirlPie

Answer (score 6):

A search yielded [**this website**](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

It shows the following formula for calculating bearing:

**θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )**

> where φ1,λ1 is the start point, φ2,λ2 the end point (Δλ is the
> difference in longitude)

**Bearing** is the horizontal  angle between the direction of an object and the true north *as defined in* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(navigation))

Bearing is different from the angle which the north needle is pointing to, for example:
[image: compass bearing example]

in this picture bearing is 330°, although the needle is pointing to 30° *(which is simply -330°)*